# Adding HTML to JQuery Isotope additems/insertitems Part 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-isotope

Following on from:

[Adding HTML to JQuery Isotope additems/insertitems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595074/adding-html-to-jquery-isotope-additems-insertitems)

I have Brady's:

```
function makeDataSlide(slideId, imgSrc, slideTitle) {
  var slide = $('<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="'+ slideId +'"></li>');
  var gridItem = $('<div class="grid-item" style="display:none"></div>');
  $(gridItem).append('<img src="'+ imgSrc +'">');
  $(gridItem).append('<h4>'+ slideTitle +'</h4>');
  $(slide).append(gridItem);
  return slide;
}

$('.button').on( 'click', function() {
    var $items = [
      makeDataSlide(8, 'img/btn.png', 'XXXXX'),
      makeDataSlide(9, 'img/btn.png', 'XXXXX'),
      makeDataSlide(10, 'img/btn.png', 'XXXXX'),
      makeDataSlide(11, 'img/btn.png', 'XXXXX'),
    ]
    $grid.isotope( 'insert', $items);
});
```

There's no errors, but the button doesn't do anything?

Comment: By doesn't do anything do you mean it does not work or it is not being executed on click?

Comment: Make sure that '$(.button').on(...)' is wrapped in $(document).ready().  

Should read:    " $(document).ready(function() { $('.button').on(...) });

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that '$(.button').on(...)' is wrapped in $(document).ready().

Should read:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.button').on(...);
});
```

Comment: However, the button still does nothing when clicked, it is clickable, just nothing happens.

Comment: @Alex, sorry meant to put that before! But no, no console errors for that function.

Comment: @fdsfdf, can you create a jsfiddle with your current code and paste the link?